# How does the :not selector work to block older browsers and for which browsers does it work?

Tags: css

How does the

```
not(#foo)
```

selector works to block older browsers and for which browsers does it work in the following tutorial?

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: As for browsers which supports the not pseudo-class, here is the link: http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

Comment: Or this link http://css3test.com/, which allows to test support of CSS3 in your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector does not block browser, it's just not supported by the browser, i.e. when CSS file is being parsed by browser's built-in parser (which in turn supports certain CSS specification), unknown selectors and rules will be ignored and won't be added into styles of frames in render tree